# Why class method argument can be narrower than that of interface

Tags: typescript, interface, narrowing

Why is this code allowed in TS?

```ts
interface IFoo {
    foo(a: string | number): void
}

class Bar implements IFoo {
    foo(a: string) { }
}
```

I think the compiler should throw error, as param `a: string` of `Bar` is narrower/not substitutable to `a: string | number` of `IFoo`.

Comment: When you add `foo(a: string)` you're explicitly typing `a` to `string`, since type `string` is assignable to `string | number` there's no error, if you don't provide any type i.e., `foo(a)` the type will be `string | number`. So, it's because of the explicit type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is deliberate design and intended behavior due to [Function Parameter Bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance).

> When comparing the types of function parameters, assignment succeeds if either the source parameter is assignable to the target parameter, or vice versa.  [...]

<sub>https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance</sub>

Essentially, this means that function types are checked in both ways. The class implementation of `foo` is not only assignable to the declaration in `IFoo` if its type is more *narrow* but also if it's *wider*. A type error only occurs if  neither the interface declaration nor the class type implementation are assignable to one another.

```ts
interface IFoo {
  foo(a: string | number): void;
}

class Bar implements IFoo {
  foo(a: string) {}
}

class Baz implements IFoo {
  foo(a: string | number | boolean) {}
}

class Invalid implements IFoo {
  foo(a: string | boolean) {}
//~~~ Property 'foo' in type 'Invalid' is not assignable...
}
```

You can prevent this by enabling [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictFunctionTypes).
However, there is another important thing to notice. The strict parameter type checking only works when declaring `foo` as an [*arrow function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`foo: (a: string | number) => void;`).

> During development of this feature, we discovered a large number of inherently unsafe class hierarchies, including some in the DOM. Because of this, the setting only applies to functions written in function syntax, not to those in method syntax.

<sub>https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictFunctionTypes</sub>

Now you get your expected parameter type checking:

```ts
interface IFoo {
  foo: (a: string | number) => void; // <- !! function syntax
}

class Bar implements IFoo {
  foo(a: string) { }
//~~~ Property 'foo' in type 'Bar' is not assignable...
}
```